# PHP. Laravel. Multiple dependency injection

Tags: php, laravel, testing, dependency-injection

I have a `Notification` class where I inject `MessageService` class that has dependency of `MessageTextService`.

```
class Notification
{
    private $messageService;

    public function __construct(MessageService $messageService)
    {
        $this->messageService = $messageService;
    }
}

class MessageService
{
    private $messageTextService;

    public function __construct(MessageTextService $messageTextService)
    {
        $this->messageTextService = $messageTextService;
    }
}
```

Using Laravel I can register `MessageService` in the ServiceContainer but then I won't be able to create a mock of `MessageService` in the tests.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the code with problem? What error do you get?

Comment: You can mock in tests like: `$this->app->instance(MessageService::class, $messageServiceMock);` Then the next time the container builds your class it will use the mock.

Comment: Show us how you are trying to mock the MessageService. Dependency injection is actually the solution to writing testable code!

Comment: Thank you all! Actually there was no problem and I used DI to run my tests.